# Output of 2-dimensional arrays in java , (take this error [[Z@6d06d69c )

Tags: java, arrays, class, boolean

```java
public class Main {
    boolean[][] Obstacle;
    int rows; 
    int cols; 

    Main(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.Obstacle = new boolean[rows][cols];
        Board();
    }

    public void Board() {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (i = 0; i < 5;) {
            int x = r.nextInt(this.cols);
            int y = r.nextInt(this.rows);
            if (Obstacle[x][y] == true) {
                Obstacle[x][y] = false;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main(6, 8, 10);
        System.out.print(m.Obstacle);

    }
}
```

---

Hi, first of all I read all the questions about the problem but I could not find the answer, I still get the same error. Normally I know that 2-dimensional boolean arrays are false by default, but I cannot get such an output. What is the problem, can you help?

I take this output:

```
[[Z@6d06d69c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output is the memory address of your ObstacleField.

You have to iterate the 2-dimensional array and print each position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.ObstacleField.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m.ObstacleField[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(m.ObstacleField[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) method to get a `String` representation of a multidimensional array:

```java
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(m.ObstacleField));
```

Output:

```
[[false, false, true], [false, false, true], [false, false, false]]
```